# How to add python code in a html email in python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, html-email

To print a variable I have used:

```
<html>
""" +str(new_oppotunity)+ """
</html>
```

How can I add a for loop to print items in a list in the html.

Comment: This what you're looking for? `"{item}".format(item=variable)`. Not quite understanding your question. It would probably help if you could include a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the [`Jinja`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) templating library. It has powerful tools that help simplify making HTML pages via Python.

A vanilla Python example that may do what you want is

```py
list_of_items = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange']

html_str = '<html>\n<ul>'
for item in list_of_items:
    html_str += '<li>' + item + '</li>\n'
html_str += '</ul>\n</html>\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to dynamically create HTML with Python rather than insert python code in an HTML document and expect it to just work.

You can create a Python CGI script that imports the jinja library. It takes an HTML template with jinja2 syntax embedded in it and fills in the template with data.